# How to run this Ex(Trello API) code on Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, trello

I want to use **Trello API** to execute on `google-apps-script`.
but `google-apps-script` does not support **ES6 promise**.

JS

```
var url = "https://api.trello.com/1/cards/{idCard}/customField/{idCustomField}/item?token={yourToken}&key={yourKey}";
var data = {value: { number: "42" }};
fetch(url, { body: JSON.stringify(data), method: 'PUT', headers: {'content-type': 'application/json'}})
.then((resp) => resp.json())
.then((data) => console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)))
.catch((err) => console.log(JSON.stringify(err, null, 2)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to convert the following script to Google Apps Script.

  ```
  var url = "https://api.trello.com/1/cards/{idCard}/customField/{idCustomField}/item?token={yourToken}&key={yourKey}";
  var data = {value: { number: "42" }};
  fetch(url, { body: JSON.stringify(data), method: 'PUT', headers: {'content-type': 'application/json'}})
  .then((resp) => resp.json())
  .then((data) => console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)))
  .catch((err) => console.log(JSON.stringify(err, null, 2)))
  ```
- Your script works fine.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Modified script:

```
var url = "https://api.trello.com/1/cards/{idCard}/customField/{idCustomField}/item?token={yourToken}&key={yourKey}";
var data = {value: { text: "42" }}; // <--- Modified
var params = {
  method: 'PUT',
  contentType: 'application/json',
  payload: JSON.stringify(data)
};
var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
Logger.log(res.getContentText())
```

- Before you run the script, please modify `url` with your parameters.

#### Note:

- There are 6 custom field types like "Text", "Number", "Date", "Checkbox" and "List".
- If you use the text field for the custom field, you can use "Text" as the Custom Field Type. It's like `{ "value": { "text": "Hello, world!" } }`.
- If you use the number field for the custom field, you can use "Number" as the Custom Field Type. It's like `{ "value": { "number": "42" } }`.

#### References:

- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String,Object))
- [/card/{idCard}/customField/{idCustomField}/item](https://developers.trello.com/reference/#customfielditemsid)

If this didn't work, I apologize.

Comment: @Ma Kun Thank you for replying. I couldn't notice that your script in your question didn't work. There are 6 custom field types like "Text", "Number", "Date", "Checkbox" and "List". The reason of error is due to that your custom field is different from the request body. If your custom field uses the text field, modify from `var data = {value: { number: "42" }};` to `var data = {value: { text: "42" }};`. If it's other type, please check the sample from [here](https://developers.trello.com/reference/#customfielditemsid).